# jfree chart set show range x value in chart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I want to create a image file using jfreechart heres my code :

```
 XYSeries xydata = new XYSeries("fitness");
    for (int i = 0; i < it; i++) {
        xydata.add(i,fitness[i]);
        //System.out.println(fitness[i]);
    }

    XYSeriesCollection fitness_series = new XYSeriesCollection();
    fitness_series.addSeries(xydata);

    //Use createXYLineChart to create the chart
    JFreeChart XYLineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("fitness", "iteration", "fitness", fitness_series, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    /* Step -3 : Write line chart to a file */
    int width = 640; /* Width of the image */
    int height = 480; /* Height of the image */
    File XYlineChart = new File("xy_line_Chart_fitness.png");
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(XYlineChart, XYLineChart, width, height);
```

and the result is :
[image: result]

but the y axis start with the first value of my set not a 0 like in the picture shown above, how do i set it to my own specific value ? or the lowest x data that i have ?

Comment: your x value starts with 0, so why you expect it to tart with some other value?

Comment: @almasshaikh sorry i mean vertical value ? it is x right? its start around 230

Comment: it is y axis. So what values does your array fitness holds? if you want to start with 0, then fitness[0] should be 0.

Comment: the values is arround 230 and up, no i want to start with the value of fitness[0] not a 0. i want to set the starting point y axis i mean the line not the data.

Comment: line is drawn as per what you specify in your array, so you cant change it.

Answer (score 1):

The NumberAxis class will, by default, calculate its range from your actual data values as well as including zero by default.  There is a flag that you can set to control whether or not zero is included:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setAutoRangeIncludesZero-boolean-